# Issue with circular dependency

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a design question.

I have three separate classes, namely A, B and C. Class A has an array object of Class B. And Class B has an object of Class C.

Now, I want to access a function from Class A in Class C.

How can I accomplish it?

Here is some code:

File classA.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <classB.h>

class classA
{
    classB objB[10];
    void GetData();
};
```

File classB.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <classC.h>
class classB
{
    classC objC;
}
```

File classC.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <classA.h>
class classC
{
    classA objA;
}
```

The above code creates a loop, even though I have added `#pragma once`. I have also tried to include the classA.h in the classC.cpp, but still I can't access the function in ClassA.

Many thanks.

Chintan

Comment: There is nothing to do with inheritance here.

Comment: Looking at the modifications you made to the question: Is the real problem the circular dependence of the header files? That's not what the title of the question suggests...

Comment: @jogojapan: Thanks. I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 3):

As @jogojapan said, this is more a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) issue.

You can use a pointer member to class A in class C and use forward declaration.

```
class classA;
class C{
    classA* objAPtr;
};
```

Then in c.cpp you can add `#include <classA.h>`

Comment: Thanks for the link and your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @chintans getting that classA ptr to the classC object at construction-time through a default-constructed array of classB objects is a whole new issue, especially if you want assurance the classA ptr is *the* classA object the that owns classC's immediate parent classB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you basically want i could think of this:

create an object of class A in class C and access the function of class A using its object that is present in class C

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method of `Class A` with its object in `Class C` then you need not to implement inheritance and if you want to call the method of `Class A` with `Class C's` object then you need to implement inheritance.